# Get в javascript

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сделать запрос к изображению, подгрузить изображение. И в тоже время, чтобы была возможность прервать процесс и начать новый.

Сейчас делаю это через XMLHttpRequest, есть какие более простые варианты, удобнее?

Comment: Чтобы была возможность определить то, когда изображение подгрузилось и готово к отображению

Comment: все зависит от того, что считать удобностью

Comment: что именно неудобно в варианте с `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) в связке с [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AbortController).

Пример:

```
var controller = new AbortController();
var signal = controller.signal;

var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download');
var abortBtn = document.querySelector('.abort');

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchVideo);

abortBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  controller.abort();
  console.log('Download aborted');
});

function fetchVideo() {
  ...
  fetch(url, {signal}).then(function(response) {
    ...
  }).catch(function(e) {
    reports.textContent = 'Download error: ' + e.message;
  })
}
```

(Скопировано с developer.mozilla.org)