# В чем тут дело?

Tags: javascript

```
(xml = new XMLHttpRequest()).open('GET', 'url.png', true);
xml.onloadend = _ => {
    //Событие сробатывает после выполнения команды xml.abort()
}
xml.send();
```

Предположим, выполняем запрос xml, до того как изображение будет подгружено, выполняю команду xml.abort().

Вроде бы все процессы должны быть остановлены. Но как только изображение подгружается, выполняется команда xml.onloadend.

Вопрос в том, как остановить слушатель xml.onloadend, для чего необходима команда abort()? Если она не останавливает привязанный слушатель loadend

Comment: не используй `onloadend` если тебе не нужно знать о неудачной загрузке

Comment: Потому что onloadend предназначен для срабатывания при любом завершении — неважно, успешном или неуспешном или через abort. Если вас интересует только успешное завершение, то используйте onload

Comment: Необходимо узнать когда изображение подгружено и добавит его в документ. Что вы предлагаете это заменить?

Comment: Зачем для изображения вообще XMLHttpRequest? У html-элемента img есть свой собственный onload

Comment: (да и даже onloadend у изображений тоже есть, хотя он не очень нужен)

Comment: Необходимо отправить запрос к изображению, получить сигнал когда изображение готово к отображению и в вставить его в html документ. Не совсем понимаю, что вы предлагаете?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов создать изображение, навесить на него onload, получить сигнал и потом вставить его в html-документ. В чём проблема?

Comment: (впрочем, [прервать процесс загрузки изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422734) таким образом может оказаться проблемой, однако при использовании XMLHttpRequest или fetch нужно иметь в виду, что после загрузки изображение может оказаться не закэшировано и при вставке в html-документ оно начнёт загружаться ещё раз)

Comment: @andreymal, это смотря как вставлять

Comment: Допустим создал объект img, указал src. Для того чтобы оно начало загружаться, необходимо вставить его в html документ, иначе загрузки не будет. Верно ли понимаю или возможно подгрузить его до вставки в html документ?

Comment: _Для того чтобы оно начало загружаться, необходимо вставить его в html документ_ - нет, загружаться начинает, как только ты src присвоил